# SQL select all rows in a single row's "history"

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID | PARENT_ID
--------------
0  | NULL
1  | 0
2  | NULL
3  | 1
4  | 2
5  | 4
6  | 3
```

Being an SQL noob, I'm not sure if I can accomplish what I would like in a single command.

What I would like is to start at row 6, and recursively follow the "history", using the PARENT_ID column to reference the ID column.

The result (in my mind) should look something like:

```
6|3
3|1
1|0
0|NULL
```

I already tried something like this:

```
SELECT T1.ID 
FROM Table T1, Table T2 
WHERE T1.ID = 6 
   OR T1.PARENT_ID = T2.PARENT_ID;
```

but that just gave me a strange result.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You want a recursive query. But as Gordon said you need provide what is your rdbms

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm using sqlite3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a [`recursive cte`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html).
If you want to start from the maximum `id`:

```
with recursive cte (id, parent_id) as (
  select t.*
  from (
    select *
    from tablename
    order by id desc
    limit 1
  ) t
  union all
  select t.*
  from tablename t inner join cte c
  on t.id = c.parent_id
)  

select * from cte
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8Xsq1eTUt7pUBorQWf18it/5).
If you want to start specifically from `id = 6`:

```
with recursive cte (id, parent_id) as (
  select *
  from tablename
  where id = 6
  union all
  select t.*
  from tablename t inner join cte c
  on t.id = c.parent_id
)
select * from cte;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8Xsq1eTUt7pUBorQWf18it/6).
Results:

```
| id  | parent_id |
| --- | --------- |
| 6   | 3         |
| 3   | 1         |
| 1   | 0         |
| 0   |           |
```